# Ember js link templates includes

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js

I am working on constructing simple Ember js template links and since I am somewhat new to Ember and I come from PHP background I tried building the idea from PHP experience on including ember templates in another template such as this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="top-nav">HTML HEADER</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">{{render 'top-nav'}} HTML body</script>
```

The idea behind it is that I want 'top-nav' template to be included in every ember template. I know {{outlet}} works in the similar matter, but it won't provide the flexibility of having few lines of code.

My question: Is there a more plausible way to insert templates into templates?

Thank you.

Comment: "but it won't provide the flexibility of having few lines of code". How could it be shorter than writing `{{outlet}}` ? Can you please clarify your concern?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way to insert a template inside of another template is simply to use a view.

```
{{view 'top-nav'}}
```

define your template like:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="top-nav">
... template markup
</script>
```

and then define your view in js

```
Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'top-nav',
});
```

and that is it. you can find more documentation on it here: http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/views/inserting-views-in-templates/

**EDIT**

as @GJK pointed out views have been deprecated as of Ember 1.13 if you are using Ember 1.13 or later I would recommend using a component instead.

```
{{top-nav}}
```

components work in a similar way that a view used to work. you can find more information about them here. ultimately it depends on what version of Ember you are using.

http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/components/

Comment: Note that views are deprecated in Ember 1.13 and removed completely in Ember 2.0 (there's a compatibility addon, but it's not meant to be used long-term).

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a more plausible way to insert templates into templates?

This is exactly what partials are for. You can read up more on partial templates [here](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/rendering-with-helpers/#toc_the-code-partial-code-helper). The gist is that you want to create your re-usable part using a filename that starts with `_`. For example:

```
{{! _header.hbs }}
<header>
    <nav>...</nav>
</header>
```

Then, you can use `{{partial 'header'}}` to drop that code right into another template (with the same context).

That being said, having a header on every page is usually a scenario where the [application template](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/the-application-template/) is most useful. You can define your application template like so:

```
{{! application.hbs }}
<header>
    <nav>...</nav>
</header>

{{outlet}}
```

This will ensure that all of your pages have the header you desire because every top-level template will be rendered inside of the outlet.

If you're having trouble deciding what to use, use partials until you run into issues. At that point, you'll probably be more equipped to deal with the application template and complex template structures.